# jQuery .animation delay issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am experiencing a problem with using the delay in jQuery's .animation function, when moving over boxes quickly the animation doesn't get triggered but when the same thing happens slowly it works without hitches. Any help adding a 500 millisecond delay without breaking the origional script in tact would be awesome, thanks.

**Original Script Without Delay:**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.learnmore', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".top", this).css({top:0}).animate({top:-205},{duration:500});
    $(".bottom", this).css({top:0}).animate({top:-210},{duration:500});
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.learnmore', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".top", this).css({top:-205}).animate({top:0},{duration:500});
    $(".bottom", this).css({top:-210}).animate({top:0},{duration:500});
});
```

**Example With Delay:** http://jsfiddle.net/nblackburn/jSPMs/

Kind Regards,
**Nathaniel Blackburn**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jSPMs/8/

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.learnmore', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    $(this).data("timer", setTimeout(function(){
        _this.data("timer", null);
        _this.find(".top").animate({top:-205},500);
        _this.find(".bottom").animate({top:-210},500)
    }, 500));

});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.learnmore', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clearTimeout($(this).data("timer"));
    if(!$(this).data("timer"))
    {
        $(".top", this).animate({top:0},500);
        $(".bottom", this).animate({top:0},500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to set CSS using `.css()` when specific callbacks are called - instead rely on `.animate()`.

Plus, you can use unqueued version of `.animate()` (just pass option `queue=false`).

As a result, your code may look like this (see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jSPMs/1/)):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.learnmore', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".top", this).delay(500).animate({top:-205},{duration:500,queue:false});
    $(".bottom", this).delay(500).animate({top:-210},{duration:500,queue:false});
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.learnmore', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".top", this).animate({top:0},{duration:500,queue:false});
    $(".bottom", this).animate({top:0},{duration:500,queue:false});
});
```

which seems to run pretty smooth. Doesn't it?

Did it help?

Comment: This is nice, but the delay doesn't seem to be working as its triggering as soon as i hover over it rather than 500 milliseconds after :(